# Django Password not receiving {{ uid }}

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Anyone familiar with the inbuilt django built in password reset?

in my url.py i'm calling

path('password-reset-confirm///', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name="password_reset_confirm"),

html is: You've requested to reset your password. Please go to the following URL to enter your new password: {{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}/password-reset-confirm/{{ uid }}/{{ token }}/

the email is showing as You've requested to reset your password. Please go to the following URL to enter your new password: http://127.0.0.1:8000/password-reset-confirm/%7B%7B uid }}/c3af5t-1c91e83e20617d5751750c6eb30e5b60/

I don't get why uid is not being recognised

I tried debugging with print statements